# Play sound on different prayer Times in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I want to play sound in my ionic2 App on different prayer Times saved in db 
e.g [this is my GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPTmR.png)

here i am playing music in opening a div like:
      in Html

```
<div item-right *ngIf="playAudio">
      <audio controls autoplay="true">
        <source [src]="this.audio">
      </audio>
</div>
```

and in my ts file:

```
    setInterval(() => {
          var d = new Date();
          var hours = d.getHours();
          var min = d.getMinutes();
          var minutes;
          if (min < 10) {
            minutes = "0" + min;
            this.time = hours + ":" + minutes;
          } else {
            this.time = hours + ":" + min;
          }
          if (this.showPrayerTimes == true) {
            this.checkprayerTime();
          }
        }, 60000)

 checkprayerTime() {

    if (this.time == this.prayerTime.FajarTime) {
      this.playAudio= true;
    }
    else if (this.time == this.prayerTime.DhuhrTime) {
      this.playAudio= true;
    }
    else if (this.time == this.prayerTime.AsrTime) {
      this.playAudio= true;
    }

    else if (this.time == this.prayerTime.MaghribTime) {
      this.playAudio= true;
    }
    else if (this.time == this.prayerTime.IshaTime) {
      this.playAudio= true;
    }
    else if (this.time == this.prayerTime.JumuahTime) {
      this.playAudio= true;
    }
    else {
      console.log("time do not match");
    }
  }
```

it is working in this current page(only when we are on this page) but what if i want to check the prayer time in my app no matter on what page i am it checks and plays audio .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my App component.ts I used set interval function and it runs in complete app and work as a background process in my app and plays sound regardless of at what page I  am.

Answer (score 0):

you can create separate Component for checking and playing and add that Component in the top of the App.
(kind of global header/footer component)

Comment: my prayer time is varying for different mosques having different schedule of prayers, then how will i send prayer time data to that component

Comment: ur Component can access the data directly

Comment: orr u can create Event Handler on the component to receive the changed data

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

Fire ur custom event and listen in the component

Comment: Thanks! what if i fire it on life cycle hook of my app at starting and setinterval function will check the timings and play the audio???